# Event Monitoring Wave Dashboards Row Count

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, eventlogfile, einstein

I am using pre-built Event Monitoring Wave Dashboard to get Report exported by users, Dashboard adoptions and performance. When I saw dashboards for how often are dashboard used I found too much Row count.

Can any one explain what is this row count. Does it mean row count in reports because as per my understanding I want to see how many time users visit particular dashboard?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me on this. I would not able ti figure out why too much Count of Rows are showing.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the total number of records in the dataset (DashboardwithUsers)

try to drill down on to the dataset to find more details

[image]

[image]

Regards,

Praneel PIDIKITI